# .NET: Do I need multitargeting for libraries?

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing a .NET class library that uses the `net6.0` target framework. The library is not using any .NET 7 features, however, there are many applications, both .NET 6 and .NET 7 that use the library. I did not notice any problems with this, so it seems as if .NET 7 is backwards compatible and can load `net6.0` class libraries.

Does it still make sense to use the multi-target `net6.0;net7.0`? Currently, everything works well with the single target `net6.0`, but I do not know whether I am missing something.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/7.0#core-net-libraries

Comment: @HansPassant Does this mean that net6.0 assemblies can be loaded by .NET 7 if it does not use any of the stuff listed under "breaking changes"?

Comment: You already know that loading is not an issue, you tried it.

Comment: Yes, of course. But sometimes, things work only by accident. I hoped to get a clear answer that what I am doing is actually the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that doesn't make sense in your case (although technically, this should be possible). Either target `net6.0` or `net7.0`. Multi-targeting is normally used to [address target platform differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting).

If your library will use .NET 7.0 features, you'll then have to upgrade your library to target `net7.0` and then users of the library will have to migrate or stick with the current version.